# How much of this 'Slow Death of the Universe' was predicted?

Tags: energy, universe, stellar-evolution

In short:
**the energy generated in today's universe, is "about half of the produced two billion years ago" and found that "this fading occurs at all wavelengths"**
as yesterday news: [ESO - Charting the Slow Death of the Universe](http://www.eso.org/public/news/eso1533/)

**I want to know:**

1. Why galaxies are producing so much less energy
2. How much of this was predicted (source & formula, for instance)

Because the measure of energy was from actual light from material sources I'm not expecting to read Dark something or space expanding in the answers.

Notes :
the [e-print](http://www.eso.org/public/archives/releases/sciencepapers/eso1533/eso1533a.pdf) 
(quote but simplified)

> ...obtain the first fully empirical measurement of the 0.1-500µm
>   energy output of the Universe. ...across three time-intervals
>
> 0.3–1.1 Gyr  -   (1.5±0.3)10^35 h70 W Mpc−3
>            1.1—1.8 Gyr
>           1.8—2.4 Gyr  -   (2.5±0.2)×10^35 h70 W Mpc−3
>
> More importantly, we identify significant and smooth evolution in the
>   integrated photon escape fraction at all wavelengths, with the UV
>   escape fraction increasing from 27(18)% at z = 0.18 in NUV(FUV) to
>   34(23)% at z = 0.06.
>   ...energy output of the Universe in three volume limited slices
>   centred at
>   0.5, 1.5, and 2.5 Gyr in look-back time. Note that by energy output we refer to the energy being generated per Mpc^3 as opposed to the energy
>   flowing through a Mpc^3. This is important as the former refers to the
>   instantaneous energy production rate of the Universe (i.e., the
>   luminosity density), whereas the latter is the integrated energy
>   production over all time, including the relic CMB photons

I look inside the pdf for the terms:
 'theor' and found none
 'cause' and found minor because's
 'calcul' minor ..
 'correct'  All distributions are extinction corrected but otherwise as observed.
 'predict'  ??

Comment: I can understand why you wouldn't want to see a "Dark" something in the answer. That would imply we don't truly understand the mechanism behind it, but what's wrong with space expansion? That is an observed and well documented phenomenon

Comment: Well the *source* of the claim is clearly displayed in Figure 25, the emissions are decreasing with decreasing $z$. Note also that science often works in the $\rm obs \to theory$ direction, rather than the $\rm theory\to obs$ direction that you seem to want here.

Comment: Space expansion do not affect matter at galaxy level and DM do not interact. *Predictions* can distinguish between models. Building patches around 'unexpected features' is depressing: DM,Inflation,DE. (In the label of a figure on Number Counts of a paper to be that I'm looking these days: *There is a large discrepancy between the Dilation model and the typical ΛCDM model, which shows that this test can directly discriminate between these two models*, see in my profile how the 'space expansion' can be seen as 'matter shrinking')  That is why I wish to know if the *news* is unexpected, or not.

Comment: It all follows from having a universe with finite mass density and a definite beginning instead of a continuous creation as was proposed in steady-state models.